# about the proof that curvature of subbundle of trivial bundle is seminegative

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

The theorem stated as follows:

> Proposition 4.3.18 The curvature $F_{\nabla_1}$ of the Chern
> connection $\nabla_1$ of a subbundle $E_1 \subset
>  E=\mathcal{O}^{\oplus r}$ (with the induced hermitian structure) is
> seminegative.
>
> ---
>
> Proof. we have $F_{\nabla_1}=-b_2 \circ b_1$.
> Thus, if $h_2$ is the induced hermitian structure on the quotient $E /
>  E_1$ then $$ h_1\left(F_{\nabla_1}(s),
>  s\right)=-h_1\left(b_2\left(b_1(s)\right), s\right)=-h_2\left(b_1(s),
>  b_1(s)\right) $$
> then it can be shown it's seminegative.

---

There is a question that confused me in the proof, the proof uses the following lemma :

**Lemma.** If $E = E_1 \oplus E_2$ then the curvature of $E_1$ and $E$ satisfies the equation that $$F_{\nabla_1} = \text{pr}_1F_\nabla  - b_2 \circ b_1$$

Where $\nabla_1$ is the connection on the subbundle $E_1$, and $b_i$ is the second fundamental form on $E_i$.

---

As we see in this lemma, we need to assume that $E_1 \subset E$ split however in the Proposition 4.3.18 above, it's not necessary that $E_1 \subset E$ split as holomorphic bundle ?

Comment: Maybe the reason is it's split as complex vector bundle, then we can gives the metric on the subbundle and quotient bundle. And the lemma above only needs to condition that it split as complex vector bundle?

Comment: Huybrechts makes a comment that in the non-holomorphic category you always have the splitting. Since we're doing hermitian geometry here, we certainly don't require a holomorphic splitting.

Comment: Got it, thank you Ted Shifrin